# Basic type guard not working if checking for null value

Tags: typescript

In my code below, I have a type guard called `isLegacyPayment`. However despite using this, and returning or throwing before the line that expects a string `const stripeId: string = payment.stripeId`, it still thinks `payment.stripeId` can possibly be null. I was trying to get this type guard to work because the inverse of this guard (which checks if it's string, which works) has a really confusing name to other devs: `isNotLegacyPayment`. Anything with `isNot` has caused major confusion. Is it possible to get `isLegacyPayment` to work below?

The error we see is:
[image]

[Here is Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiAthAdsKBeKBvAUFKAZ2ACcBLSASQBMAuKFAVwBtmoAfI0slAcwG5cAX1wAzRigDGwMgHsUUMoQAyEXnEkh4SVMAA8AFSgQAHsFTVCsMpIDWe7cjQAaKAHJi5KtTcA%20XwAUYAhOwPQGAJT0wTpoilZGAGQ4XF4QNPRMrFBCOPhQJBDAjCQKMaEAdJ4U6dSYGFhZzIIiuGIS0nIK5sQBEXkEkvLEUOW69I66mCnV3vRuAIwATADMSwtuOYL5ZKJQAUqq6pqTaEEhuhH9eAQEwAAWJLIA7gwQrwCiJE8kAW6UVmYag0IFGFzQbgiggIrUGw3Qs1q9GqfGmYzQVW43m2QiAA) of code below:

```
type Payment = {
  stripeId: null | string;
}

function isLegacyPayment<T extends Pick<Payment, 'stripeId'>>(payment: T): payment is T & { stripeId: null } {
  return payment.stripeId === null;
}


function test() {
  const payment: Payment = { stripeId: '12321' };

  if (isLegacyPayment(payment)) {
    throw new Error('Is legacy payment');
  }

  const stripeId: string = payment.stripeId; // The error is here it says "Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

}
```

Comment: Without *negated types* (as in [ms/TS#29317](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)) or *fine-grained type predicates* (as in [ms/TS#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048)) this is not possible in general, unfortunately.  Type predicates work by either filtering top-level unions (and `Payment` is not a union) or by intersecting with the narrowed type (which does not affect the else side), so you're stuck.  You could either negate the sense of the type guard (which you don't want to do) or use `{stripeId: string} | {stripeId: null}` instead of `Payment`.

Comment: (see prev comment) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks way much @jcalz - it does answer it - those Github issues are amazing read. I think I need to go with union as Julio answered below. My problem is when I make `isLegacyPayment<T extends Pick<Payment, 'stripeId'>(payment: T): payment is TLegacyPayment` - all the other keys of the generic are now wiped. :(

Comment: Since you accepted the other answer I won't bother writing one up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get isLegacyPayment to work below?

It's a tricky one, where the problem I think is mainly due to the fact that `&` is intersection (combination) of types as opposed to `|` which is union (alternative), so that code is sort of backwards...

Here is how I could make it work, but 1) I have had to introduce few new types, and 2) now in the `if` branch the type of `payment` is `never`; so this might not fit your scenario:

```
type Payment = {
  stripeId: null | string;
}

type LegacyPayment = Payment & {
  stripeId: null;
}

type CurrentPayment = Payment & {
  stripeId: string;
}

type NewPayment = LegacyPayment | CurrentPayment;

function isLegacyPayment(payment: NewPayment): payment is LegacyPayment {
  return payment.stripeId === null;
}

function test() {
  const payment: NewPayment = { stripeId: '12321' };

  //if (payment.stripeId === null) {  // this works too
  if (isLegacyPayment(payment)) {
    payment;  // const payment: never  (!!)

    throw new Error('Is legacy payment');
  }

  payment;           // const payment: CurrentPayment
  payment.stripeId;  // (property) stripeId: string

}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiAthAdsKBeKBvAUFKAZ2ACcBLSASQBMAuKFAVwBtmoAfI0slAcwG5cAX1y5QkKABkIvOAGMQ8JKnRYlyNFABkOfF3JU6DFs0Eix4aAGFGJEivUrMsBBvQ68BYgYg163ngFhUXFoADkIAHdHTSxpWQUY9E4bOwdXFUFcADNGFDlgMgB7FCgyQnj5RQy0AAowGuB6COjGgEp6BuVNcqkZKqTdAntgW1KutwA6AMNMDCwmVjNRXPzCkqhgCGJatqGoORLiKAmVZqjBrGx9Cl8jAHIARgAmAGZnx-uoISyCAHo-mRslB6o1ptxZvMFiY9tcoADNgALXqRIokADWhE2RSKeiBIPKlUSjVB3WAbVhegIpzQ-H%20fwOR3QNKaDAgADcICQCLUAIS8tqiAgEYCIkhFSJsyUAUTsaNq90oWOY-QUJ0a9zaggI5mpjTpwsNwoRhxQxxZ9FS9jQST0LPBPhoBoR9XFkBIoD2Mzu-m4fFEIiAA)

Comment: Oh wow this is really smart, thank you! It's totally fair for me to add those types, that will help a ton actually. Thank you!

Comment: Oh one difficulty, there are actually a whole bunch of other keys in `TPayment`. So I need `isLegacyPayment` to still respect the `T` generic. Man thats a tricky one.

Comment: It all works even if you add properties to Payment...  I can edit my answer adding an example "extra" property, if you think it's useful.

Comment: Ah I mean if my my type I passed to it was already narrowed, passing it to `isLegacyPayment` now undoess all the narrowing and sets it to type `LegacyPayment`.

Comment: But the devil, especially with these things, is in the detail: my `isLegacyPayment` sets the type to `never`, and rather relevant is that it takes `NewPayment` in input, i.e. irrespective of any narrowing of what you pass to it...  I think you are facing a next level of issues here, so you should ask a new question with more specific code/a more specific case at this point.

Comment: Haha thanks very much really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh wow you're right, it does retain other narrowings! Thank you! In this example I also narrowed if it has refunds. Thanks very much! https://tsplay.dev/mMlvbN